# Trying to change image on hover but getting $var.attr is not a function error

Tags: jquery, arrays, attributes, typeerror, each

I am trying to change a thumbnail on hovering over another smaller thumbnail (show color variation). There are multiple groups of images on the page. The HTML is generated dynamically so I am assigning IDs via JQuery.

The code I am using to assign id to each image (this works fine):

```
$('.pretty-item .image-container > a img').each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr("id","id" + index);
  });
```

The problem line in the code:

```
$('.pretty-item .image-container > a img').each(function() {
var $mainImg = $(this).attr('id');
$(".catalog-tiny-thumbnail").mouseover(function(){
var src = $(this).attr("src");
var doubleWidth = $(this).width()*2;
var doubleHeight = $(this).height()*2;
$mainImg.attr($("src"),src);
$mainImg.css({"width":doubleWidth,
                                "height:":doubleHeight});
});
});
```

The $mainImg.attr($("src"), src); is giving the Uncaught TypeError: $mainImage.attr is not a function

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That gives the same error as well.

Comment: $mainImg is an id as I just noticed, so $mainImg.attr($("src"),src); should be $("#" + mainImg).attr("src", src).

Comment: Beautiful! That works! Thank you. However the hover on small img is changing the src on all large images on the page. Should I separate the functions?

Comment: If it's possible for you, yes. But what should happen on mouseout? Should the original image then be displayed again? I made a Fiddle with a different approach (setting the ids of the mainimages as data-attribute to the thumbnail-images) https://jsfiddle.net/1b94c56z/

Comment: OK. Yes thats perfect. How would I set it to show original image on mouseout?

Comment: You could set the url of the original image as data-attribute to the thumbnail image like in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1b94c56z/1/

Comment: Awesome! Got it. That helps a ton. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) I just posted an answer to your original question though it was already answered in the comments. Please accept this answer by checking the checkmark next to it so your question can be resolved as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$mainImg` is just the id of an image, so

```
 $mainImg.attr($("src"),src);
```

should be

```
 $("#" + $mainImg).attr("src",src);
```

The same applies to

```
 $mainImg.css({"width":doubleWidth,"height:":doubleHeight});
```

which should be

```
 $("#" + $mainImg).css({"width":doubleWidth,"height:":doubleHeight});
```